# PHP mail send code not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this coding but its not processing, and its not outputing any errors.

```
function send_email($subject='Activate Your Account', $html_content, $text_content, $headers) { 

    $en['email'] = 'test@email.com';
    $to = $en['email'];
    $en['memb_id'] = '39';
    $en['confcode'] = '69696969';
    $en['user'] = 'couple';

    $text_content = "Confirm Your domain.com Account\r\n";
    $text_content.= "UserName: " . $en['user'] . "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Activate Your Account by visiting this link below:\r\n";
    $text_content.= "http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "______________________\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Thanks,\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Staff";

    $html_content = "<html><body><h1>Confirm Your domain.com Account</h1>";
    $html_content.= "<p>UserName: " . $en['user'] . "<br>";
    $html_content.= "Activate Your Account by visiting this link below:<br>";
    $html_content.= "<a href=http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . ">http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . "</a>";
    $html_content.= "</p>";
    $html_content.= "______________________<br>";   
    $html_content.= "Thanks,<br>";
    $html_content.= " Staff";
    $html_content.= "</body></html>";

    $mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

    $body = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $text_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";

    $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $html_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";

    $headers.= 'From: <support@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "X-Sender-IP: $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Date: '.date('n/d/Y g:i A')."\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Reply-To: <support@domain.com>' . "\r\n";

    return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    echo $to;
    echo $subject;
    echo $body;
    echo $headers;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a mail server configured on your server? if not, then that's the problem.

Comment: Can you give more details on what it is doing?

Comment: Are you sure all the variables are set correctlY? ex: you have a $header as to $headers

Comment: yes my mail server is configured correctly i've been using an old mail() code, i'm trying to upgrade to something that will do html & text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last bit has me confused:

```
return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo $to;
echo $subject;
echo $body;
echo $headers;
```

You know that none of those `echo` statements are going to get executed because they are after the `return` right?

Try using `error_log` to verify steps in the script or viewing the error log itself if you haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHPMailer/Lite](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). Save yourself the MIME headache.

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I fixed it for you. I checked it and it's working good. Also make sure that your hosting supports mail() function. If SMTP is not enabled, then you wont be able to send mail for sure.

**REVISED CODE:**

```
<?php 
function send_email($subject='Activate Your Account') { 

    $en['email'] = 'test@email.com';
    $to = $en['email'];
    $en['memb_id'] = '39';
    $en['confcode'] = '69696969';
    $en['user'] = 'couple';

    $text_content = "Confirm Your domain.com Account\r\n";
    $text_content.= "UserName: " . $en['user'] . "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Activate Your Account by visiting this link below:\r\n";
    $text_content.= "http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "\r\n";
    $text_content.= "______________________\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Thanks,\r\n";
    $text_content.= "Staff";

    $html_content = "<html><body><h1>Confirm Your domain.com Account</h1>";
    $html_content.= "<p>UserName: " . $en['user'] . "<br>";
    $html_content.= "Activate Your Account by visiting this link below:<br>";
    $html_content.= "<a href=http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . ">http://www.domain.com/confirm/" . $en['memb_id'] . "/" . $en['confcode'] . "</a>";
    $html_content.= "</p>";
    $html_content.= "______________________<br>";   
    $html_content.= "Thanks,<br>";
    $html_content.= " Staff";
    $html_content.= "</body></html>";

    $mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

    $body = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $text_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";

    $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $body.= $html_content;
    $body.= "\n\n";
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";

    $headers.= 'From: <support@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "X-Sender-IP: $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Date: '.date('n/d/Y g:i A')."\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Reply-To: <support@domain.com>' . "\r\n";

    return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

    }

?>
```

Hope that helps. Let us know.